# How to position element and make it responsive

Tags: css

I have my element like this

[image]

Here is the Css for 1,2,Send element

```
 .card {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 350px;
  margin: 2rem auto !important;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

I want to achieve this result , and make this + button near the number 1 element.

[image]

and make my element responsive on all devices.

Is there a Way to do it ?

I tried to change the element 1 css like this .

```
.card1 {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 250px;
    margin: 2rem auto auto 11rem !important;
    padding: 20px;
  }
```

The problem is that it's not getting responsive on various device .

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/joostvdhorst/571wsokp/

Answer (score 0):

You can use @media queries in css.
With this you can specify various screen sizes and apply properties based on it.

Comment: The problem is, that the send and the second element are ok but the first one is not responsive :/

Comment: Share the css for +. Better create a working example in fiddle/plunker?

Comment: .plus{
`
font-size: 35px;
background-color: $white-love;
}`

Comment: try with `display: inline-block;` for plus and first element in media queries.